# If $V$ is a complex vector space and $W$ be a real vector space(finite dimensional),then the basis of $W$,$V$ are same.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $V$ is a complex vector space and $W$ be a real vector subspace (finite dimensional) of V.For each $\alpha \in V$ there are unique vectors $\beta$, $\gamma$ in $W$ such that:

$$\alpha = \beta + i\gamma$$

Prove that the basis of $W$, $V$ are same.

This is an exercise from Hoffman and Kunze. I dont need help with the proof of the theorem but I was thinking of examples and came up with the following example which seems to contradict the statement.

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be a vs over $\mathbb{C}$ then the basis is $\{1\}$ and the basis of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is $\{1,i\}$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Typo? For each $\alpha \in V$?

Answer (score 3):

Note that—as [Paul Frost](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/349785/paul-frost) suggests in his comment on your question—you have misquoted condition (b) of Exercise 14, which is:

> For each $\ \alpha \in V\ $ [N.B. *not* $\ \alpha \in W\ $] there are unique vectors $\ \beta$, $\ \gamma$ in $W$ such that:
> $$\alpha = \beta + i\gamma$$

Your example of taking $\ W=V=\mathbb{C}\ $ doesn't satisfy this condition, because (for instance) if we take $\ \alpha=1\in V\ $ then we have:
\begin{align}
\gamma&=1+0i\ \ \ \ \ \text{, and}\\
\gamma&=0+(-i)i\ ,
\end{align}
and $\ 1,0,-i\in W $, so the decomposition of $\ \gamma\ $ as $\ \beta + i\gamma\ $ with $\ \beta,\gamma\in W\ $ is not unique.

Comment: Ok so why have they mentioned that $V$ is a complex vector space?Also if I treat $V$ and $W$ as spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ then let us assume $V$ to be $\mathbb{C}$ over $R$ ,then basis of V is $\{1,i\}$ and $W$ to be $\mathbb{R}$ and the basis of $W$ over $R$ is {1}.They are not equal but W is a subspace of $V$

Comment: My apologies for earlier misdiagnosing the problem.  My assertion that Hoffmann and Kunze must have meant $\ V\ $ to be taken as a vector space over $\ \mathbb{R}\ $ was wrong.   What's going on here is that if $\ w_1, w_2,\dots,w_n\ $ is a basis of $\ W\ $ and $\ W,V\ $ satisfy condition (b) of Exercise 14, then $\ w_1, w_2,\dots,w_n\ $ will be linearly independent in $\ V\ $ *as a vector space over* $\ \mathbb{C}\ $, and any $\ v\in V\ $ can be be written as $\ c_1w_1+c_2w_2+\dots+c_nw_n\ $ with $\ c_i\in\mathbb{C}\ $ for all $\ i\ $.

Comment: In your second example, where you take $\ W= \mathbb{R}\ $ and $\ V=\mathbb{C}\ $, which alerted me to the error in my original answer, the spaces $\ W\ $ and $\ V\ $ *do* now satisfy condition (b) of Exercise 14.  But now a basis of $\ W\ $ consists of a single non-zero number, and will also be a basis of $\ V\ $, considered as a *complex* vector space.